# Kinetic Energy of pendulum with moving support

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, reference-frames

I am trying to calculate the kinetic energy of a pendulum with moving support. I have come across two ways that could be used to calculate the kinetic energy, and although I know that the first of them is the correct derivation, I am quite confused as to why the second one isn't correct.

[image]

For the purpose of solving this question, I am not looking to find the kinetic energy of m1, only of m2.

These are the two approaches I found:

1. The coordinates of m2 are:

$x'(t)=x(t)+l\cdot sin(\theta)$

$y'(t)=l\cdot sin(\theta)$

such that the velocity of the object is

$\dot x'(t)=\dot x(t)+l\cdot cos(\theta)\dot\theta$

$\dot y'(t)=-l\cdot sin(\theta)\dot\theta$

And as such: $T=m_2/2 \cdot (\dot x^2+2\dot x\dot \theta lcos(\theta)+l^2\dot\theta^2)$

2. We calculate the kinetic energy summing up the linear and rotational kinetic energy such that:

$T=m_2/2(\dot x^2)+1/2(I\omega^2)=m_2/2(\dot x^2+l^2\dot \theta)$

There seems to be a difference between the two calculations to a factor of $2\dot x\dot \theta lcos(\theta)$ and I don't fully understand why the second approach would be incorrect in terms of physical intuition. I would be glad if anyone could clarify why physically there is no superposition of the two "types" of kinetic energy present in this problem.

Comment: Note that it is $y(t) =cos(\theta ) l $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If (x) is changing with time then $m_2$ cannot be considered as rotating about $m_1$.  In the simple case where $m_1$ is sliding without friction on a horizontal rod, $m_2$ would be swinging under the center of mass.

Comment: Thanks! I think that the fact it is swinging under the center of mass was what I was missing for the intuitive explanation.